# Sigmachip Keyboard is not functioning on Tablet

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have an new Tablet Micromax P681 and Sigmachip Micro USB keyboard but it is not functioning, what can be the issue, please help

Answer (score 0):

Dude check the stripe underneath keyboard.

I had the same problem, at morning a tablet keyboard case was delivered home after connecting to tab input keyboard was detected as Sigmachip Micro USB keyboard but I was unable to get any key like "**B**" "**R**" "**T**" "**P**" etc. so I open up the case & notice there was strip underneath the keyboard (strip is located just below those keyboard leds in front **be very careful while opening the front side of keyboard you might tear a part those strip** by profession I open such items regularly) which was not connected properly I reconnected the strip now my keyboard is operational. Open your case in a clean way so that even when you fix it to after.

But I am still going to replace my product as few keys are not working at all, from customer point of view I didn't buy that product to fix it by my self.